# Getting seed and using random numbers in ExUnit test cases

Tags: random, elixir

I have a test case that needs to use random integer, so I have:

```
test "test with random integer" do      
  IO.inspect :random.uniform(10)
  assert true
end
```

This always prints 4 when I run it, even though I can see different seeds in console output:

```
Randomized with seed 197796
...
Randomized with seed 124069
```

I know I should use `:random.seed/1` or `:random.seed/3`. I want to use the same seed as is printed at the end of test output. This way if my test fails I can replicate it with

```
mix test --seed 124069
```

I can't do that if I am using `:random.seed(:erlang.now)` for example.

How can I get the seed that ExUnit uses for randomizing its test cases inside the test case?

Comment: You might have just run into the problem of getting the same 'random' value because you were using `:random`, i.e. the `random` Erlang/OTP module. I saw the same behavior just now when I used `:random.uniform/1` versus `:rand.uniform/1`, and the latter did NOT need to be seeded anyways!

Answer (score 7):

In the latest versions of Elixir, the following code *will* now return the seed used by `ExUnit`, even if one isn't specified manually:

```
ExUnit.configuration()[:seed]
```

The seed wasn't available via `ExUnit.configuration` in previous version *unless* it was manually specified. Instead, you could set the seed yourself, e.g. in your `test_helpers.exs` file:

```
ExUnit.configure seed: elem(:os.timestamp, 2)
```

Setting the seed like that is [how `ExUnit` did so itself](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/1067ab10df73089f963972a6db6b903ff5286814/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/runner.ex#L54) at one point.

In either case, in your test code you can do:

```
s = ExUnit.configuration |> Keyword.get(:seed)
:rand.seed(:exsss, {s, s, s}) #random enough for me
IO.inspect :rand.uniform(5)
```

Every time you run the tests you'll get a nice random value, but if you use:

```
$ mix test --seed <seed>
```

you will get the same value every time.

##### Note about `:random`

From [the docs for `:random`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/random.html):

> #### Note
>
> The improved [`rand`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html) module is to be used instead of this module.

Comment: This answer is outdated, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56210387/162337

Comment: The answer is outdated because `ExUnit.configuration()[:seed]` _will_ return the seed now (as-of Elixir 1.11.3 anyways), even if its not provided to Mix via the `--seed` option.

Comment: The answer _should_ be now-dated now.

Answer (score 4):

As of the time of this answer, the random seed is available inside of your tests by calling:

```
ExUnit.configuration()[:seed]
```

This is super nice for any tests that are dynamic by having random numbers but need to be repeatable for debugging, which was the goal of the question. If you wanted a number between 0-9, for example, you could use:

```
  seedable_random_number_under_10 = rem(ExUnit.configuration()[:seed], 10)
```